# Why do I get a first empty element in a vector?

Tags: r, vector

I am new in programming and currently struggling with R. I have to put 6 elements in a new vector `'badmonths'` after a comparison of 12 elements in the vector `'profitaftertax'`. My problem is I get 7 elements where the first one is empty. Could you explain me why?

```
mean <- mean(profitaftertax)
badmonths <- c('')

for(i in profitaftertax) {
    if (i < mean) {
      # print(i)
      badmonths <- rbind(badmonths, i)
    }
}
print(as.numeric(badmonths))
```

The result is:

```
[1] NA  1337.973 -2595.453 -2040.017  -419.944 -1567.055  461.720
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you start by intializing the first element as an empty string, and then add numbers to the string. Try instead the following. This will initialize `badmonths` to an empty vector.

```
mean <- mean(profitaftertax)
badmonths <- numeric()

for (i in profitaftertax) {
    if (i < mean) 
        {#print(i)
    badmonths <- rbind(badmonths,i)}
            }
print(badmonths)
```

You can understand this further by trying the following:

```
as.numeric('')
```

Comment: Thank you!!! It works, I did know this function before, now I have got it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear that! If you think it solved the problem, it would be nice if you could click the button next to the answer, to mark it as solved. Good luck with your R programming!

Comment: Hey~why to use `rbind()` rather than `c()` in your for loop? It will return a matrix and it's not convenient.

Comment: Totally agree with you there. My intent was to answer the question only.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

The other answer shows why you get the NA. But you really shouldn't use a loop for this

```
badmonths <- profitaftertax[profitaftertax < mean(profitaftertax)]
```

Comment: Thanks, Dason. I just learning, as I said :). Do I understand right, by this line I create a new vector by filtering the old one?